# getting a value of time from void function

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

how to get the value of TIME in this example so i can use it in my main code, which is in the save javaFile. I tried doing a public String time and then in code using like clock1=time;

Just to be more clear of what i am trying to achive:

This in in my main code:

```
        spinner_dailyInput.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner_dailyInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){

                    case 1:
                        for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
                            setTimePicker();
                            clock1=time;
                        }

                        break;
```

This is basicly a spinned, if a user selects for example 1, he will get 1 (select time), now i need to save the time he inputs to a variable for further use. If the user selects 2 for example he will get a clock, input time click save (this needs to save to Clock1), then another timepicker pops up (again pick time and then save to Clock2).

```
   public void setTimePicker(){
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                hr=String.valueOf(selectedHour);
                mini=String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                time=hr+":"+mini;
                Log.e(TAG+".........TimePicker.....................",time+"");

            }
        }, hour, minute, true);
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }
```

Comment: You can use an instance variable, only the variable declared in the methods need to be final to be accessible in a nested method (can't remember the name of that notation...)

Comment: use global variable or static variables, or send a object as parameter to add your time value; it is depend on your code.

Comment: What 'time' do you mean?

Comment: Where you face NullPointerException?

Comment: Ok . I wrote my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     spinner_dailyInput.setAdapter(adapter3);
    spinner_dailyInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){

                case 1:
                    for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
                        setTimePicker(i);
                        //clock1=time; <--- wrong. time is still null here
                    }

                    break;
                    }
        }
    }

     public void setTimePicker(final int i){
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    hr=String.valueOf(selectedHour);
                    mini=String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                    time=hr+":"+mini;
                    Log.e(TAG+".........TimePicker.....................",time+"");
                mySimpleCallback(i, time)';//<---- not null here
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }


    private void mySimpleCallback(int i, String time ) {
    //not null here because it fires after your code execution
if (i == 0)
    clock1 = time;
else
clock2 = time;
    }
```

Comment: what if the user selects 2, how can i save first clock value to "clock1" and the second one  to "clock2"

Answer (score 0):

```
String time = null;
public void setTimePicker(){
        ...
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                ...
                time=hr+":"+mini;
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);
        ...
        //Here, time could still be null if mTimePicker.show(); is an asynchronous call (most likely)
    }
```

After the call of `onTimeSet`, the variable `time` in the instance will hold the value you want. But this call **can be asynchronous**, if so, don't expect to get the value directly at the end of `setTimePicker()` call, the value would only occurs after the user inputs the value in the TimerPickerDialog shown.

Comment: If you read the text before his code he already did that you've written

Comment: @Vyacheslav read my last line. I am editing to add where it could occurs. I tried to be more explicite about the problem, reduce the code length too (not that important but easier to explain)

Comment: so how can i get this value after the user inputs it and save it to a variable (check my update)

Comment: @jan Different question but the short version would be that you need to send a signal to notify the reception of a value. An event, a callback, ...